# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:96 (install): install TARGETS given unknown argument "NAMELINK_COMPONENT"

Tags: cmake

I am writing a CMakeLists.txt to compile and install my programs. I have following error with the below install() command. I need to install a symbolic link (additionally to the library so file) for the created library.

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:96 (install): install TARGETS given
>   unknown argument "NAMELINK_COMPONENT".

```
install(TARGETS my-library
        LIBRARY
          DESTINATION /usr/lib/
          COMPONENT Libraries
          NAMELINK_COMPONENT Development
       )
```

I am following the instructions given in the CMake documentation (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html#). is this because of cmake version in my PC or syntax error ?
please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have same version of CMake (v3.13) or newer.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason. my cmake version is 3.10.2 and I was referring to an update version. thanks for helping.